# Why my panel is hiding the body of my views?

Tags: react-native

i want to build a built a navigation with `BottomTabNavigator` but i dont know what happen i never see the body of my screens, something is hidding the body, i created a demo to demostrate you the wrong, but its too simple.

this is the file App.js

```
import React from 'react'
//import { Provider } from 'react-native-paper'
import { Provider, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        height: 100,
        padding: 20,
      }}
    >
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', flex: 0.3 }} />
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', flex: 0.5 }} />
      <Text>Hello World!</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        flex: 1,
        color: 'green',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="main">
        <Stack.Screen name="loginScreen" component={SettingsScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="main" component={MyTabs} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

i am trying to do, before to user is logged i would like to hidde the tabs

something is hidding

[image]

edit 1: why i have 2 headers?

[image]

Comment: Can we connect for a short meeting and solve together, if yes reach me at emmbyiringiro@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the web, `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs` mistakenly treat screens in the tab as inactive and detaches them.

The solution is to disable detach inactive screens for bottom tab.

```js
import React from "react";
//import { Provider } from 'react-native-paper'
import { Provider, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flexDirection: "row",
        height: 100,
        padding: 20,
      }}
    >
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: "blue", flex: 0.3 }} />
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: "red", flex: 0.5 }} />
      <Text>Hello World!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "red",
        flex: 1,
        color: "green",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator detachInactiveScreens={false}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{headerShown:false}} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="main"  >
        <Stack.Screen name="loginScreen" component={SettingsScreen}  options={{headerShown:false}}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="main" component={MyTabs} options={{headerShown:false}}  />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: why i have two headers, can i remove 1?

Comment: Check updated solution, you can customize it as you want

Comment: how can i keep just one header¿

Comment: Set `headerShown:true` on screen you need it

Answer (score 0):

**Moving between screens**

You can create a state for handling user logged in status or you can also use redux for it so It will automatically navigate to the main screen after user logged in

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {state.userToken == null ? (
          // No token found, user isn't signed in
          <Stack.Screen name="loginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
        ) : (
          // User is signed in
          <Stack.Screen name="main" component={MyTabs} />
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

More details [Here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/)

Comment: the error is like the gif, css are hidding the body